# using SSH to access ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, windows, ssh

Suppose I set up 2 PC's running ubuntu and windows. Windows is being used to ssh into ubuntu pc, so which PC's resources will be used for the connection and the work done over ssh ?

Suppose I make windows pc powerful by adding better components, and ubuntu pc is just powerful enough to power on. So if I ssh from windows to ubuntu, which pc's resources will be used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSH connection itself uses resources on Windows (e.g. PUTTY) **and** Ubuntu. The network connection is both ways, so 15kbps of data transfer uses 15kbps on both client *and* server.

But if you execute action/commands, it will be run on the Ubuntu server and uses the resources there. If you run a resource intensive program, calculations are run on the server, but anything that displays in the terminal is transmitted to the SSH client.

Comment: What kind of resource does it use on Windows ? BTW i am running remote desktop connection

Comment: what SSH tool you will use on Windows? PUTTY?

Comment: This is what i did. Installed xrdp on ubuntu -> ifconfig for ip -> fired up windows remote desktop connection -> entered my ip and boom , everything is working

Comment: That's not SSH @Ashok. That's RDP.

Comment: @Zacharee1 oops my mistake ! My apologies!